# Java Fraction Calculator

Tags: java, calculator, jgrasp

I don't know why my fractions won't reduce. I think it's because I didn't call it but I don't know where to call it. (sorry the spacing is so bad. they never check that at school)

```
import java.util.*;
public class FracCalc_Egg {

   public static String f1;
   public static String op;
   public static String f2;
   public static int w1;
   public static int w2;
   public static int n1;
   public static int n2;
   public static int d1;
   public static int d2;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Welcome to the Fraction calculator!");
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter an expression (or \"quit\"): ");
      //get the first fraction, or quit
  f1 = console.next();
  //test fraction1 to see if the user types "quit"
  if(f1.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
     System.out.println("Goodbye!");
  }
  while(!f1.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
     op = console.next();
     f2 = console.next();
     processFractions(f1, op, f2);
     System.out.print("Enter an expression (or \"quit\"): ");
     f1 = console.next();
     if(f1.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
     System.out.println("Goodbye!");
     }
  }//end while loop
  //while loop continues the calc until the user types "quit"
   }//end of main


  public static void processFractions(String f1, String op, String f2){
  //get int variables from fractions

  //testing fraction 1 to get int values
    if(f1.contains("_")){ //testing for mixed number
     w1=Integer.parseInt(f1.substring(0,f1.indexOf("_")));
     n1=Integer.parseInt(f1.substring(f1.indexOf("_")+1,f1.indexOf("/")));
     d1=Integer.parseInt(f1.substring(f1.indexOf("/")+1));
     n1=(w1*d1)+n1; //making mixed number improper
  } else if(f1.contains("/")) { //testing for fraction
     n1=Integer.parseInt(f1.substring(0,f1.indexOf("/")));
     d1=Integer.parseInt(f1.substring(f1.indexOf("/")+1));
  } else {//testing for whole number
     w1=Integer.parseInt(f1.substring(0));
     n1=w1;
     d1=1;
  }//end if, else if, else method

  //testing fraction 2 to get int values 
  if(f2.contains("_")){ //mixed fraction
     w2=Integer.parseInt(f2.substring(0,f2.indexOf("_")));
     n2=Integer.parseInt(f2.substring(f2.indexOf("_")+1,f2.indexOf("/")));
     d2=Integer.parseInt(f2.substring(f2.indexOf("/")+1));
     n2=w2*d2+n2;  
  } else if(f2.contains("/")) { //fraction 
     n2=Integer.parseInt(f2.substring(0,f2.indexOf("/")));
     d2=Integer.parseInt(f2.substring(f2.indexOf("/")+1));
  } else { //whole number 
     w2=Integer.parseInt(f2.substring(0));
     n2=w2;
     d2=1;
  }//end if, else if, else method


  dotheMath(n1, n2, d1, d2, op);

   }//end processFraction method    

//dotheMath detmerines the operator 
 public static void dotheMath(int n1, int n2, int d1, int d2, String op) {
   if(op.equals("+")){
       System.out.println(add(n1, n2, d1, d2));     
    } else if(op.equals("-")) { 
       n2=-1*n2;
       System.out.println(add(n1, n2, d1, d2)); 
    } else if(op.equals("*")) {
       System.out.println(multiply(n1, n2, d1, d2));
    } else { 
       int x = n2;
       int y = d2;
       d2=x;
       n2=y;
       System.out.println(multiply(n1, n2, d1, d2));
    } //end the if, else if, else statement

 }//end dotheMath method


 public static String add(int n1, int n2, int d1, int d2) {
    int newn = (n1*d2) + (n2*d1);
    int newd = d1*d2;
    int divisor = reduce(newn,newd);
    newn/=divisor;
    newd/=divisor;
    String answer = newn+"/"+newd;

    return answer;
 }//end add method


 public static String multiply(int n1, int n2, int d1, int d2) {
    int newn = n1*n2;
    int newd = d1*d2;
    int divisor = reduce(newn,newd);
    newn/=divisor;
    newd/=divisor;

    String answer = newn+"/"+newd;
    return answer;
 }//end multiply method  


 public static int lcd(int n1,int d1, int n2, int d2){
   int dividend=(d1*n2)+(n1*d2); 
   int divisor = d1*d2;
   int rem = dividend % divisor;
   while (rem != 0){
     dividend = divisor;
     divisor = rem;
     rem = dividend % divisor;
  }  

 return divisor;
   } //end lcd   


public static int reduce (int newn, int newd) { //
int newn_abs = Math.abs (newn);
int newd_abs = Math.abs (newd); //

 int min_num = Math.min (newn_abs, newd_abs);

int divisor = 1;

for (int i = 1; i <= min_num; i++) {
 if (newn%i == 0 && newd%i == 0){

 divisor = 1;
 }//end if 
   }//end for
   return divisor;

}//end reduce


}//end of class
```

example-
Welcome to the Fraction calculator!
Enter an expression (or "quit"): 1/4 + 1_1/2
14/8
the expected output is 1_3/4
and I'm stuck right at the reduce method. someone told me in class that I didn't call that method but I don't know what they mean. They told me to call it in the add and multiply method but how/where do you do that?

Comment: could you provide a small running example with sample input and expected output and in addition mark the position where you are stuck. At the moment it seems like we need to guess where you are stuck and having problems.

Answer (score 1):

When you class mates tell you, that you didn't **call** the reduce method, they mean, that you never **use** the reduce method.

Your add-method should look somewhat like this:

```
 public static String add(int n1, int n2, int d1, int d2) {
    int newn = (n1*d2) + (n2*d1);
    int newd = d1*d2;

    int divisor = reduce(newn, newd);
    newn/=divisor;
    newd/=divisor;
    int integerComponent=0;

    while(newn >= newd) {
        integerComponent++;
        newn-=newd;
    }
    String answer ="";
    if(integerComponent>0) {
        answer += integerComponent +"_";
    }
    if(newn!=0) {
        answer += newn+"/"+newd;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

and the multiply method should look like this:

```
public static String multiply(int n1, int n2, int d1, int d2) {
    int newn = n1*n2;
    int newd = d1*d2;

    int divisor = reduce(newn, newd);
    newn/=divisor;
    newd/=divisor;

    int integerComponent=0;

    while(newn >= newd) {
        integerComponent++;
        newn-=newd;
    }
    String answer ="";
    if(integerComponent>0) {
        answer += integerComponent +"_";
    }
    if(newn!=0) {
        answer += newn+"/"+newd;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Remember that you also have to change your reduce method, as it always returns 1 right now!

**Edit:** Added code to print fraction as mixed fraction.

Comment: Nice answer, just to add a little note. Before you call `String answer = newn+"/"+newd` you also need to somehow handle improper fractions.

Comment: I assumed that the intention of the reduce function is to provide a correct divisor. If it works there shouldn't be any improper fractions at this point, or am I wrong?

Comment: Since `reduce` only returns the divisor, if you have a fraction like 8/6, reduce will return 2, and your code will bring it to 4/3. From my understanding of the question, the expected outside in this case would be 1_1/3. So, she needs to add a couple of extra lines so code to convert 4/3 to 1_1/3. Kinda like the inverse of `processFractions`.

Comment: Thank you guys both for the help! I was working on this after school and I think someone was talking about having a method in order to return a mixed fraction. Is that what you're talking about @Zequ? I'm working on fixing my indentation and reduce method because like @Nyli said it's only returning 1. First time using this website and its already been a lot of help. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, exactly, @e-kim, you have a `processFractions` method for converting input, you need something to do the opposite. No worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Before I get to my answer, I just have one request, please, please fix your indentation. By providing newly formatted, easy to code in your question, you're much more likely to get an answer and much more likely to get a high quality answer.

Now, for my answer. This is a school project, you're supposed to learn through it. On that note, I won't give you the full answer but I will try to guide you. So, a couple of things, firstly, your friend is right, and secondly, your reduce function is incorrect. You are generating a function in two places, in your `add` function and in your `multiply` function at the line:

```
String answer = newn+"/"+newd;
```

What you have to do instead at this step is call your reduce function in

```
String answer = reduce(newn, newd);
```

Now, it's up to you to change the reduce function to properly reduce the fraction and handle improper fractions.